# Visual Studio - build .exe file using dll

Tags: dll, .net-assembly

I created a solution with multiple projects(A and B, A is a dll). I need to get the running executable file of B which is running relying on B. However, after I change the location of B and run B.exe, it gives me an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'A, version = 5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot fine the file specified.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `How can I solve this problem?` ...you move A to wherever you moved B?  If B depends on A, then A has to be in a place where B can find it.

Comment: Clearly your expectations about "only need to get the running executable file of B" do not align with reality of B requiring assembly A... Please [edit] post to separate what you want from what you get. So far there is no real problem to solve...

Comment: @BJMyers Do I need to specify the path of A to B？

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for suggestion, I will do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally you should move your dll's with your app otherwise you could also complain why one should install the .NET Framework on the machine.

Anyway, if you would have to have self contained .net application you could use [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura). Just install it via NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

and it will hook up your build process and during build it will add the necessary code to get the dll's from .exe so that everything will work.